# Updating multiple documents in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, updates

I have the following data in my database mongodb

```
> db.poepledatas.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef83e24b5b88209109affbd"), "name" : "eren", "age" : 30, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef85fef14e2da588c79683a"), "name" : "lixi", "age" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef866df14e2da588c79683b"), "name" : "deku", "age" : 29 }
```

i want to update the "age" field of the above documents with names eren and lixi to 40
is there a way to do this in one update command

i have been trying to do the following

```
personModel.updateMany({name:"eren",name:"lixi"},{age:40},function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    console.log("updated");
  }
});
```

But the above code only seems to change the age to 40 for only one record with the name "lixi"

```
> db.poepledatas.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef83e24b5b88209109affbd"), "name" : "eren", "age" : 30, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef85fef14e2da588c79683a"), "name" : "lixi", "age" : 40 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef866df14e2da588c79683b"), "name" : "deku", "age" : 29 }
```

any way to update both the docs "name" eren and lixi to "age"=40 in one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have Or condition

```
 {"$or" : [{name:"eren"}, {name:"lixi"}]}
```

Your update statement should be

```
{"$set" :{age:40}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

Also you had a minor syntax error in your update section. you did not use an update operator like `$set`. As it will work as a [replacement document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-method-replacement-document) with this syntax.

```
personModel.updateMany({name: {$in: ["lixi", "eren"]}}, {$set: {age: 40}}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("updated");
    }
});
```